# Using AspectJ to intercept method call and bind it to another method

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, interceptor

I am new to AOP, have gone through the tutorials here: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/ and have basic understanding of how aspects work.

This is what I am trying to do.

There is an @annotation called "MyAnnotation" and lets say I have a method decorated like this

```
@MyAnnotation
public void MyMethod() {
    //something here
}
```

I have written an aspect class like this:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect { 

@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
public void MyAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint p) throws Throwable {
    // I want to call an intereceptor here, for example
    SomeInterceptor.invoke(methodInvocation)
    p.proceed();
}
}
```

`SomeInterceptor` is in a dependency package and I don't own the code. It extends the `MethodInterceptor` class in `org.aopalliance.intercept`. It does some processing that I need to do in my advice method before `MyMethod` is called. I cannot use `Guice.bindInterceptor` and is looking for a similar alternative. I am not sure how can I get the `methodInvocation` object that I can pass to invoke method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed: https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/tree/master/docs/sandbox/aopalliance

This is the bridge between aspectJ and AOPAlliance.